# JSF hidden:input for boolean field

Tags: jsf, hidden-field

I have the following class:

```
public class FilterUsers{
 private boolean isAdmin;

 public boolean isAdmin() {
    return isAdmin;
}

 public void setIsAdmin(boolean isAdmin) {
    this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
}
}
```

I'm trying to make the admin field true through a hidden input in a JSF form. How would I do that?

I was thinking at something like: h:inputHidden value="#{filterUsers.isAdmin}"

Thank you

Comment: How does that make sense? Why not just use a checkbox or a button to set it to true? What exactly is it, the problem you thought to solve using a hidden input?

Comment: @MihneaMihai - why does the `isAdmin` flag have to be present in the view? You know you can view hidden params by looking in the generated HTML source in the browser right?

Comment: @BalusC - The class FilterUsers returns a list of users based on different criterias inputed in a jsf form. I want to deny the user who is searching the posibility of selecting if the admin property is true or not and automaticaly insert the admin as true. How should I do that?

Comment: @kolossus I may have the code wrong but I'm trying to set the isAdmin property through the view. And I want it automatically set to true.

Comment: Just do it directly in the model?

Comment: @BalusC - Unfortunately I can't because the class FilterUsers can also be called from different forms where I need the isAdmin to be false. Isn't there a way to automaticaly set a property regardless of the user input?

Comment: I mean, you can very easily add another action method which toggles that boolean property. Or you can just parameterize the action method. Or you can just subclass it and set some default values.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{managedBean.booleanAttribute}">
  <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Boolean" />
</h:inputHidden>
```